# android-x86 on Oracle VirtualBox sound don't work

Tags: android, virtual-machine, virtualbox, android-x86

I'm using Windows 7, i installed android-x86 on Oracle VirtualBox, but sound isn't working. I changed AudioController to SoundBlaster16 but it still not working

Comment: THis site is for android programming questions.  Advice on how to run android is off topic.

Comment: Even if it wasn't off-topic, I think a simple web search would get you what you needed; at least to get to the point where you could post something to Android Enthusiasts SE

Comment: "Isn't working" isn't really a problem description.